# Only output to first instance of the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this WordPress function:

```
function content_before_after($content) {
    return 'something goes here';
} 
add_filter('the_content', 'content_before_after');
```

...which works fine except for one small problem: If there is more than one instance of the_content() on any page template, the returned text will appear for each of them.

For reasons I can't go into I won't be able to modify the templates.

But the problem I need to be solved is: how can I change this function so that the returned text is only output into the first instance of the_content() of my page template?

Comment: is there any other conditions which is apply for your first instance?

Comment: @dipmala No. I was hoping for that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here **static** variable will help you:

```
function content_before_after($content) {
    // define variable as static
    static $content_shown;

    // if variable has __no__ value
    // it means we run function for the first time
    if (!$content_shown) {
        // change value and return required string
        $content_shown = true;
        return 'something goes here';
    }

    // empty string will be returned in second and other function calls
    return '';
}
```

Comment: will that prevent all the other instances of the_content() from showing other content? I still need it to let any other instances output whatever they are supposed to.

Comment: What other content are you talking about? This function just returns string `something goes here` __only for the first time__ it is called. All other calls return empty string.

Comment: Ah yes of course, and you're right it works. Nice solution - thanks a bunch. However I just realised a problem - if one of the WordPress templates only has one instance of the_content() then nothing is returned at all.